# Self-referencing Classes as Aggregate Roots

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

Self-referencing and hierarchical structures are not uncommon in real-world software projects. One can think of many examples:

- Category of Products
- A Tree-like Structure of Geographical Regions
- etc.

The question is, as of Domain-Driven Design principles, can a self-referencing class be selected as **Aggregate Root**? Can you give an example of how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can a self-referencing class be selected as Aggregate Root

If I had to express a large hierarchical homogeneous tree as an Aggregate Root I would most likely introduce a different class (homogeneous except for the root then) for the root entity, such as `CategoryRoot 1--* Category 1--* Category` which removes the need of asking this question.

If you really want the same class (not sure if it's advisable) then you would still need some kind of protocol in place to make sure that the root instance is treated differently from child entities although they are the same class. For instance, you would need to only allow repositories to return top-level `Category` (e.g. `parent = null`) instances and nested `Category` instances shouldn't be made accessible nor referenced without their root.

Comment: I agree with this.  I have a rather [old post](http://www.ebenroux.co.za/design/2010/08/19/natrual-aggregates-vs-synthetic-aggregates/) along these lines.

Comment: Can you show me a code sample?