# relationship aggregate root itself in DDD

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aggregate, domain-driven-design

I have an **AggregateRoot** called ***category***. Which has a **Paret Id** connection with itself .In **DDD(domain-driven-design)**, how can I do this?

```
public class Category{

              public int Id { get; set; }
              public string Name { get; set; }
              public int ParentId{ get; set; }
              public int RootId { get; set; }

}
```

***Edit:***

> I have an old project that I want to convert to DDD. I have a problem
> in the relationship between the Category table and itself.

I wrote this code. But in the **AddParentCategory**, I can not check whether this category has duplicate subcategories or not?
Is the relationship I have built right?

```
public class Category : AggregateRoot
{
    public static Result<Category> Create(Category parentCategory, string name)
    {
        var result = new Result<Category>();


        var nameResult = Name.Create(value: name);

        result.WithErrors(errors: nameResult.Errors);

        if (result.IsFailed)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var returnValue = new Category(name: nameResult.Value, parentCategory: parentCategory);

        result.WithValue(value: returnValue);

        return result;
    }

    private Category() : base()
    {
        _products = new();
    }

    private Category(Name name, Category parentCategory) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
        ParentCategory = parentCategory;
    }

    public Name Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; private set; }



    public Result<Category> AddParentCategory(string categoryName)
    {
        var result = new Result<Category>();
        var hasAny = this.ParentCategory.Name.Value.ToLower() == categoryName.ToLower();

        if (hasAny)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format(Validations.Repetitive, DataDictionary.CityName);

            result.WithError(errorMessage: errorMessage);

            return result;
        }

        result = Category.Create(parentCategory: this, name: categoryName);

        if (result.IsFailed)
        {
            return result.ToResult();
        }

        return result.ToResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @SurajRao My questions have nothing to do with copying and pasting code

Comment: Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images

Comment: @Jazb The photo was removed and the code was inserted.

Comment: I think [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317711/12100772) will help You.

Comment: @quain Can you show me a code sample?